# In Corda, is there an upper limit of the size of attachments?

Tags: corda

In Corda, attachments can be added to a transaction. Is there any upper limit on the size of these attachments?

Answer (score 0):

As of Corda 3.1, one of the network map parameters specified by the network operator is `maxTransactionSize`. `maxTransactionSize` specifies the maximum size for a `LedgerTransaction` (i.e. fully-resolved transaction including attachments).